# What can we say about the fields if the subfields generated by the squares are isomorphic?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field. If $f(T) \in \mathbb{Z}[T]$ is a polynomial of degree less than the characteristic of $F$ (if the characteristic of $F$ is $0$, take it as it were $\infty$), then I believe it is pretty easy to show by induction on degree of $f(T)$ that the subfield generated by $\{f(x) : x \in F\}$ is equal to $F$. (Look at the polynomial $f(T+1)-f(T)$ whose degree is exactly one less than the degree of $f(T)$.) Let now $E$ and $F$ be two fields of characteristic 2. Suppose that their subfields generated by the squares are isomorphic. Can we say that the fields $E$ and $F$ are isomorphic? Same question can be asked for any prime $p > 2$. By the way, if $SL_2(E) \simeq SL_2(F)$, then (some of us know that) the subfields of $E$ and $F$ generated by the squares are isomorphic. So the question arises: Assuming $SL_2(E) \simeq SL_2(F)$ (with characteristics equal to 2, otherwise it is known), can we say that $E\simeq F$?

Answer (score 2):

For a field $F$ of characteristic $2$, $F \to F$, $x \mapsto x^2$ is a ring/field isomorphism from $F$ onto its image $F^2$. So if $F$ and $L$ are such that $F^2 \simeq L^2$, then $F$ and $L$ are isomorphic